# JS Append not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to append something to a div and it's not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var itx = "<h1 class='thx'>teste</h1><p class='tx'>teste</p>";
var ima = "<img class='bg rs' src='"../templates/eso/images/BANNER.jpg' />";
$(".box1").append(ima);
$( ".menu-text-info" ).append(itx);
</script>
```

Somehow this code is not working now, I can't figure out why.

Comment: Verify that your selectors are finding elements.  That's step one.

Comment: You need to fix your mis-matched quotes. You can clearly see the problem from the syntax highlighting in the question

Comment: how could I verify that ? using some kind of alert?

Comment: Fix your syntax error first

Comment: Thanks a lot ! that was my problem lol, but since this was in a php echo the problem was on the database it inserted a "

Comment: However, for furture reference.  You can verify that a selector found elements by doing `console.log($('theSelector').length);` and seeing that the console prints > 0

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your source is correct for the image and the quotation marks match up like this and it should work fine:

```js
var itx = "<h1 class='thx'>teste</h1><p class='tx'>teste</p>";
var ima = "<img class='bg rs' src='../templates/eso/images/BANNER.jpg'/>"
$(".box1").append(ima);
$(".menu-text-info").append(itx);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box1"></div>
<div class="menu-text-info"></div>
```